# the left hand side of the assignment is not a variable?

Tags: java

I am trying to set this up so my tests will work but I keep getting an error about the left-hand side of the assignment is not a variable on the line starting with 'flunking.gpa...'. Any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

```
/**
 * After we have added hours and quality points, we need to 
 * check that the gpa is (quality points) / hours
 */ 
@Test
public void gpa() {  
    flunking.gpa() = flunking.qualityPoints() / (double)flunking.hours();
    assertEquals(flunking.gpa(), 0.0, DELTA);
}
```

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory, `flunking.gpa()` is not a variable.

Comment: Here you are trying to assign value to a method instead of variable that causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to assign a value to a method

```
flunking.gpa() = flunking.qualityPoints() / (double)flunking.hours();
```

As both `qualityPoints` and `hours` contain values within the `flunking` classs, there's should be no need for any assignment here, i.e. just have `gpa` return the calculated value  in that class as required, e.g.

```
public double getGPA() {
   return qualityPoints / (double)hours; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a `flunking.setGpa(newValue)` or `flunking.gpa(newValue)` method to change the value? `.gpa()` just returns the value and it doesn't make sense to assign to it, technically speaking.